# Cannot connect to server using Karma-runner

Tags: google-chrome, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm working through the AngularJS official tutorial [(step-2) http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02], but for some reason I can't run through the karma-runner. Here is the log.

---

WARN [karma]: Port 8005 in use

WARN [karma]: Port 8006 in use

WARN [karma]: Port 8007 in use

INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.1 server started at http ://local host:8008/

INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome

INFO [Chrome 28.0.1500 (Mac OS X 10.8.4)]: Connected on socket id F5_Rx3lz-COSRuJ6PttM

Chrome 28.0.1500 (Mac OS X 10.8.4): Executed 0 of 0 DISCONNECTED (0.64 secs / 0 secs)

WARN [Chrome 28.0.1500 (Mac OS X 10.8.4)]: Disconnected

---

**Spec:**

Node: 0.10.13 
Karma: 0.10.1
Mac OS Mountain Lion

**Three additional things I have to point out:**

1) if i look at the console of http ://local host:8008/debug.html, it says "SUCCESS PhoneCat controllers PhoneListCtrl should create "phones" model with 3 phones". This is the correct response to the test as the expected outcome from the tutorial shows "Chrome 22.0: Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.093 secs / 0.004 secs)"

2) in the same Chrome browser that is running karma-runner, i can't connect to any websites in new tabs.

3) if i look at the Mac OSX's Console log, it says:

Google Chrome: stat on /private/var/folders/x4/jr57pd9j2m7671r225lhj3xw0000gn/T/karma-9387260/Default/Bookmarks: No such file or directory

I think this has to do with the disconnection, but I have no idea how to fix this bug.

Thanks!

Comment: Try running karma with - - log-level debug option. Can you post the log content?

Comment: @MichaelBenford Yup, here is the output: https://gist.github.com/alwc/6241123

Comment: oh my god you won't believe me... after I ran the test with --log-level debug, the issue is finally resolved... I don't know why, but thanks @MichaelBenford! I've been working on this for two days.

Comment: ok, i realized it's not because of the --log-level debug. it's because of Tmux!it seems karma-runner doesn't work inside tmux for some reasons. http://savanne.be/804-running-karma-and-chrome-under-tmux-on-osx/